# Resizing NSWindows and fixed ratios in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, scale, nsview, nswindow, resize

I was looking into making a window that has a fixed ratio when the user resizes the NSWindow element in Mac OS X.

I originally tried:

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize
{
    NSSize windowSize = frameSize;
    windowSize.width = windowSize.height*1.6;

    return windowSize;
}
```

Which does the basic job, apart from this will only work if the user drags the window from the bottom or corner, NOT from the sides.

So I had another look and I found the following:

```
[_window setAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(1.6, 1)];
```

(I put this in applicationDidFinishLaunching:)

This initially looked like it was going to do the job, however when you go to resize the window it will jump initially, and then work fine.

Also, my graphics seam to look fuzzy when the window gets enlarged, even thought the quality f them is bigger than the window size.

Basically, I was hoping if anybody had any tips and tricks for a new Mac OS X developer on changing the window size. I never had to worry about this for iOS, and I want to work this out before I redesign the apps UI for the larger screen size.

Thanks!

Comment: You say it jumps; are you setting the initial aspect ratio correctly in IB?

Comment: You can do that? Where would I find it because I can't see it in the NSWindow's properties.

Comment: Yeah, it's in the Size Inspector (5th tab in the right-hand pane).

Comment: Am I being blind but I can't see a 'aspect ratio' property here. http://cl.ly/1r243G0c0l2v1u3N2p2c (P.s. Ive changed my aspect ratio to 0.75).

Comment: What you're setting in IB is the content rect. The window frame (effectively the title bar) is not included. This would correspond to the aspect ratio maintained by `-setContentAspectRatio:`. That is, if you set the content size to have a particular ratio in IB and want that maintained at runtime, use `-setContentAspectRatio:`. If, on the other hand, you want the aspect ratio of the frame maintained, you can use `-setAspectRatio:` but you need to make sure you specify a slightly different content rect so that the frame starts with your desired ratio.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks @KenThomases. That does the job nicely. Do you know why my images (NSImageView) go gets fuzzy when the window resizes? Do I have to tell the window to redraw?

Comment: What is the nature of the image? If it's a bitmap, then scaling it up can't add detail that isn't there. It's going to get fuzzy and/or jaggy/blocky.

Comment: @KenThomases It's a PNG so yes, it's a bitmap, but it's twice the size it's displayed initially. I did this so that when the user scales the view, the image is still a good quality.

Comment: What happens if you start the window (and image view) at the larger size? Does it show a sharp image then? I'm wondering if the image is somehow being cached at its initial size (although I thought the framework had stopped doing that).

Comment: Yeah, if I start it full screen, it's sharp. But if I start it small and resize, it is fuzzy. How would I refresh the cache if it is doing that?